# Cordova Android app do not receive FCM notifications from server side

Tags: android, asp.net, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been stuck in a Cordova Android app problem, I'm try to receive FCM notifications through Firebase plugin for Cordova, everytime I send notification through Firebase console the device receive the message, but when I try to use Firebase API on my server side, it says that the notifications it was send (status 200), but the device do not receive any notification.

Even when I try to test send notification by Postman, the same occurs, the send staus 200 appears, but no message arrives on the device.

My server side is build on .NET. Please, if someone could helpe me, I will apreciate.

```
Public Function SendNotificationToFirebaseCloud() As [String]
    Dim result = "-1"
    Dim webAddr = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

    Dim httpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(webAddr), HttpWebRequest)
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=MY_AUTHORIZATION_KEY")
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"

    Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        Dim json As String = "{""to"" : ""MY_FIREBASE_TOKEN"", ""priority"": ""high"", ""data"" : { ""name"" : ""VIP"", ""othername"" : ""Leiloes"" }}"
        streamWriter.Write(json)
        streamWriter.Flush()
    End Using

    Dim httpResponse = DirectCast(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Using streamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a "notification" field in your JSON, as the structure needs to be :

```
{
    "to" : "xxxx", 
    "priority" : "high", 
    "notification" : {
        "title" : "Your title",
        "body" : "Your body",
        "click_action" : "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY", //(This one is important as it's used to trigger the event when you click on the notification)
        "icon" : "myicon",
        "sound" : "default"
    },
    "data" : {
        "name" : "VIP", 
        "othername" : "Leiloes"
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your solution @NicolasAlric, but still the same situation.

Comment: Try to add 
    `"title" : "Your title",
    "body" : "Your body"`
to your data field

Comment: Still not working at al. I think the json format is correct, however, the problem occurs in sending the message from Firebase to the device. The status of the post request is 200, everything is ok until the firebase, however, the message is not passed on.

Comment: You can try to use topics to make this work, 
`'to' => "/topics/yourtopic"` in your JSON
`FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic("yourtopic"');` in your app code